# Python : List duplicates values when appending

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a code with two line items

lineitem:
**{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Apple', 'product_number': 'A090','quantity': '8',  'current_cost': '198.76'}
{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Orange', 'product_number': 'O8U8', 'quantity': '1','current_cost': '118.64'}**

I want to create a list with some of the data in LineCode
Below is my code:

```py
LineCode =  res['response']['data']['GetFruitList']

ValuesinList = []
dictionary = {}
keys = ['ShippingAddress', 'ProductNumber', 'Quantity', 'Price', 'LineCode', 'Count']

for lineitem in LineCode:
    LineCode = lineitem.get('line_code')
    ProductNumber = lineitem.get('product_number')
    Quantity = lineitem.get('quantity')

    values = [ShippingAddress, ProductNumber, Quantity, Price, LineCode, 'Many']
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        dictionary[key] = value
    print("print"+str(dictionary))
ValuesinList.append(dictionary)
print(ValuesinList)
```

So here I parse through LineCode , and append the needed information like LineCode,ProductNumber,Quantity,Price into a dictionary which is later appended to a list, but currently when I run the code, it gives ValueinList as :

```
[{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Orange', 'product_number': 'O8U8', 'quantity': '1'},{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Orange', 'product_number': 'O8U8', 'quantity': '1'}]
```

which is it appends the last value twice. What I want is,

```
[{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Apple', 'product_number': 'A090','quantity': '8'},{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Orange', 'product_number': 'O8U8', 'quantity': '1'}]
```

Comment: I don't understand. The last code snippet is `"what i want"`, but at the top of your post, you say you have `LineCode` which is the same thing.

Comment: Sorry that was lineitem @quamrana

Comment: Still the same thing.

Comment: but i just want few data of line item , @quamrana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ValuesinList = []
LineCode = [{'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Orange', 
         'product_number': 'O8U8', 'quantity': '1',
         'current_cost': '118.64'},
        {'line_code': 'UU', 'product_name': 'Orange', 
         'product_number': 'O8U8', 'quantity': '1',
         'current_cost': '118.64'}]

for lineitem in LineCode: 
    dicct = {}
    dicct['ShippingAddress'] = lineitem.get('line_code')
    dicct['ProductNumber'] = lineitem.get('product_number')
    dicct['Quantity'] = lineitem.get('quantity')
    dicct['Price'] = lineitem.get('current_cost')
    print("Price inside the List sending "+str(dicct['Price']))
    print("print"+str(dicct))
    ValuesinList.append(dicct)

print(ValuesinList)
```

Hope it helps